# how to read hidden value from td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to read the hidden value from td when the checkbox is checked. This is required to pass as parameter to another function.

My table -

```
   <tbody>
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
<tr>
    <td> 
        @{var val = counter++;}      
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].ShouldImport, new { @class = "sid", @onclick = "DisplayDetailedInfo(this)" })  
        <input id="hiddendata" type="hidden" value=@val name="tablerow" /> 
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].Name)
        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].AccountNumber)
        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].AccountNumber)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].AccountType)
        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].AccountType)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].AccountStatus)
        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].AccountStatus)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].IsLatePayment)
    </td>           
</tr>
}
```

My Jquery Function is as follows -

```
    function DisplayDetailedInfo(data) {         
        var checkboxChecked = $(data).is(':checked');        
        if (checkboxChecked)
        {      
            var hiddenval = $(data).find('#hiddendata').val();                       
            console.log(hiddenval);
         }           
    }
```

My Jquery output is undefined. Pls correct me what is the mistake I am doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you creating invalid html because you have multiple elements with `id="hiddendata` but the hidden input is not really required. Instead store the value in table cells `data` attribute

```
@{ var val = counter++; }     
<td data-val="@val">
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].ShouldImport, new { @class = "sid" })
</td>
```

Next you should use [unobtrusive javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) rather than polluting you markup with behavior

```
$('.sid').click(function() {
  if($(this).is(':checked'))
  {
    var val = $(this).closest('td').data('val');
    console.log(val);
  }
});
```

The reason your current code does not work is that `$(data).find(..)` is attempting to find child elements of the checkbox (which don't exist). But the following would work `var hiddenval = $(data).closest('td').find('#hiddendata').val();`

Side note: It appears that the value of `val` is the same as `i` (in the `for` loop), so it could be just `<td data-val="@i">`

Comment: Thanks. It really helped!